# How to Initialize the Qubits in IBM Quantum Composer

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

**Step 1 Qisqit :**
Here is the code of Qiskit. I have initialized the four qubits.

```
qr1 = QuantumRegister(4)
mea = ClassicalRegister(2) 
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr1,mea) 
initial=[[1,0],[0,1]]

circuit.initialize(initial[1], 0)
circuit.initialize(initial[1], 1)

#  Uc 
circuit.x(qr1[1])
circuit.ccx(qr1[0],qr1[1],qr1[2])
circuit.x(qr1[0])
circuit.x(qr1[1])
circuit.ccx(qr1[0],qr1[1],qr1[3])
circuit.x(qr1[0])
```

**Its Circut:**

[image]

**Step 2 IBM Qunatum Composer:**
Here is no such tool to initialize the qubis. Please guide me how to initilize here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The OpenQASM language](https://github.com/openqasm/openqasm) is the standard for exchange circuits among several quantum computing tools. You can use to move your Qiskit circuit to the IBM Quantum Composer.

```py
print(circuit.qasm())
```

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
gate multiplex1_reverse_dg q0 { ry(pi) q0; }
...
```

You can take the output and paste it in the OpenQASM 2.0 box in IBM Quantum Composer.

**Note**: At the moment, there is [an issue in Qiskit that QASM-exports a circuit with `initialize` instructions as "gates"](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7750). For your specific case, you need to do `decompose` first:

```py
print(circuit.decompose().qasm())
```

**Detailed explanation of `initialize`**: Qiskit [`initialize` is a `reset` followed by a state preparation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.Initialize.html). Take the following example:

```py
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1) 
circuit.initialize([0,1], 0)
print(circuit.decompose().qasm())
```

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
gate multiplex1_reverse_dg q0 { ry(pi) q0; }   #3
gate disentangler_dg q0 { multiplex1_reverse_dg q0; }
gate state_preparation(param0,param1) q0 { disentangler_dg q0; }
qreg q[1];
reset q[0];                  #1
state_preparation(0,1) q[0]; #2
```

In `#1`, the `reset`, followed by `state_preparation` in `#2`. After some nested calling, the standard `ry` is called in `#3`. In this case, `circuit.initialize([0,1], 0)` is equivalent to `reset q0[0]; ry(pi) q0[0]`.

Comment: But why there is no initializing symbol in IBM Composer

Comment: Because different tools support different instruction sets. Both Qiskit and IBM Quantum composer support a superset of the OpenQASM 2.0 instruction set. Both can rewrite their operations in terms of OpenQASM 2.0 and use that to talk to each other. Interoperability among tools is hard.

Comment: But I am a little bit confused, about how these two are the same, mean initialize in Qiskit or in QASM. Can you little bit explain it. ?

Comment: Qiskit `initialize` is a `reset` followed by a state preparation (see https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.extensions.Initialize.html). It's instruction that is composed by these two operations, like a routine calling other subroutines in regular procedural programming. I added an explanation of a OpenQASM2 to illustrate that. You could implement your own `initialize` for this case in IBM Quantum Experience with `reset q0[0]; x q0[0]`.